# IBM Worklight - Can't open localhost:8080/console in browser

Tags: tomcat7, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to preview my Worklight app in my browser, but when I open localhost:8080/console in the browser this error appears:

> HTTP Status 404 - /console
>
> type Status report
>
> message /console
>
> description The requested resource (/console) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.21

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the context root in the URL. It should be: `http://localhost:8080/your-context-root/console`.

The value of the context root is usually the name of the .war file - the name of your project. Try that.

Tip: also make sure you have set it in both worklight.properties and application-descriptor.xml, otherwise your application will fail to connect to the server, now that you have moved from Eclipse to an application server.

Some topics of worth from the [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp):

- [Transporting Worklight applications to test and production environments](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_transporting_apps_and_adapters.html)
- [Deploying a customization .war file to an application server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_deploying_customization_war_file_to_application_server.html)

Comment: Hello Idan as we know, for deploying worklight adapter we need to connect application to worklight server with live IP address(server), meanwhile if we have 1500 user of application then what should be the configuration for my server?